# How to use typed variable in class?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of php in a class with a typed variable, when I try to access the method even if it is null I get an error

[image]

[image]

```
<?php

class City
{
    private string $id;
    private string $name;

    public function getId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(string $id): City
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): City
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}

$city = new City();
$x = $city->getName();
```

I expected the same behavior as php whether or not the variable is typed

Comment: In PHP, when you declare a typed property, you must either provide a default value or set its value before accessing it.

Comment: You should initialize all the properties in the `__construct()` method.

Comment: See https://php.watch/versions/7.4/typed-properties#uninitialized

Comment: I tried, it also gave error
    public function __construct(string $id = null, string $name = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: using constructor 
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign null to property City::$id of type string

Comment: `null` is not a string. If you want a property that can be a string *or* null, use `?string` instead of `string` as the type.

Comment: to work I needed to change to ?string and assign null
private ?string $id = null;
private ?string $name= null;

Comment: Why not default to empty strings? `private string $id = "";`

Answer (score 3):

When a type is declared, all properties will have an uninitialized state. It is not allowed to access class properties prior to assigning an explicit value.

You can check if a class property is uninitialized using `isset($foo->name)`. Because this value is not the same as `null`, You cannot use `$foo->name === null` to check if the property is uninitialized.

```
 var_dump($foo->name === null);
```

In the above Code, If the $name property is uninitialized, This will throw an error:

```
Error: Typed property Example::$name must not be accessed before initialization in..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give a class property a type that isn't nullable and provide no default value, you'll receive an error if the property's value is accessed before being set.

You would need to change to:

```php
private ?string $id = null;
private ?string $name = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, when you have a typed property (as of PHP 7.4) or a typed return type in a method, attempting to access that property or call that method on an instance with a null value can lead to a fatal error. PHP's type system is strict, and it enforces type safety. If you specify a type for a property or method, PHP expects that the value will conform to that type. If it doesn't, it raises an error.

we have a City class with a private property $name, which is initialized in the constructor. The getName() method is expected to return a string. When we create an instance of the City class with a valid name and then call getName(), it should work correctly.

```js
class City {
  private string $name;

  public
  function __construct(string $name) {
    $this - > name = $name;
  }

  public
  function getName(): string {
    return $this - > name;
  }
}

$city = new City("New York");

$x = $city - > getName();
```